# Adding your Ideas as Edits to a Question

Tags: discussion, editing

I came across a question recently in the Chemistry SE. I thought about it a bit and came up with some diagrams, or some other explanation or clarification that could help potential answerers understand exactly what the doubt is.

Should I or should I not add these additional elements to that question?

Should I post a new question referring to the other question instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general I would edit, *if and only if* these two criteria are fulfilled:

1. the edit improves the question (in this case, especially in terms of clarity)
2. the edit does not distort the meaning of the original author

I like to believe that all my edits improve questions, and you have the right to believe so as well.

However, the second criterion is tougher: if you are not completely sure what the author is referring to, it is better to err on the side of caution and drop a comment asking for clarification.

But if you *are* sure, then feel free to edit, and thank you in advance for improving posts.